# Android Studio Dark Theme Function

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-dark-theme

There's is a problem with the dark/light mode function.When I want to turn on dark mode theme it seems that it writes the name of my app in the toolbar, something that I don't want. For example : [image]

It should be like this:                                                                                       [image]
I don't know why I have this problem when I turn on dark mode theme.

```
  This is my code: 

package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;


import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate;
import androidx.preference.ListPreference;
import androidx.preference.Preference;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;

public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {


    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);


        ListPreference themePreference=findPreference("theme");
        assert themePreference != null;
        themePreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener((preference, newValue) -> {
            if(newValue.equals("light_mode"))
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);

            if(newValue.equals("dark_mode"))
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
            if(newValue.equals("system_default"))
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);

            return true;
        });


    }
}
```

I don't know if it helps but here is themes.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->


    </style>







</resources>                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                               
 Here is theme.xml/night:



 <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="Theme.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
            <!-- Primary brand color. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
            <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
            <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
            <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
            <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
            <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
            <!-- Status bar color. -->
            <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">@color/black</item>
    
    
    
    
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    
    
    
        </style>
    
    </resources>
```

Comment: Can you share your layout and theme for better understanding of the problem?

Comment: The problem is the theme is adding the default `Toolbar` below yours. Be sure to have `android:windowNoTitle=true/android:windowActionBar=false` in your Activity theme (both light & dark)

Comment: @MatPag I wrote this code everywhere and that toolbar is still there.I don't know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

instead of android:windowNoTitle=true/android:windowActionBar=false

use

```
windowNoTitle=true
windowActionBar=false
```

ie without android prefix